# Single-ended to differential ADC driver with one pole active low pass filter

Tags: adc, filter, differential, low-pass, active-filter

I have this ADC driver circuit:

[image]

There is a passive filter downstream of the driver which works as desired. I'm focused here on the active filter. When I run AC analysis on this circuit configured for a differential input I get the desired and identical frequency response at Vout+ and Vout-

[image]

However I need single-ended input. I've configured the circuit in LTSpice like this:

[image]

Running AC analysis there is a difference in the frequency response between Vout+ and Vout-

[image]

How can I modify this circuit to provide the (symmetrical) frequency response I get with differential inputs using a single-ended input?

Comment: You should link the data sheet for the differential amplifier.

Comment: The main lowpass is still symmetrical. That higher frequency feature is not related to it. Probably specific to the used amplifier.

Comment: You'll probably need to convert your single ended output to a differential one. Something [like this](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/adc-driving-single-ended-to-differential-conversion.html).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen isn't the output already differential?

Comment: @davegravy You said you need the filter's input to be driven by a single ended output. So if you intend on keeping the filter's differential output then you need to convert your source's output to be able to drive the filter's differential input.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I see. The point of the circuit I posted is to do the single-ended to differential conversion as well as low pass filter. Are you saying these two functions need to be done in two separate stages?